# i, I, o, O packet inspection points inside a Check Point firewall

Tags: network, firewalls, check-point

In a Check Point firewall, can you please explain what occurs between the POSTIN (I) and PREOUT (o) inspection points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between the POSTIN (I) and PREOUT (o) inspection points most of the policy processing/routing is done.

So the question is actually what is not done between POSTIN (I) and PREOUT (o).

This includes (not a complete list, depends on version and implementation):

- Packet sanity checks - IP options and state checking.
- VPN decryption/encryption - Packets are decrypted before processing by
  rule base.
- SecureXL processing – Packets are accelerated and may
  bypass POSTIN-PREOUT altogether if packets were already allowed
  through policy and traffic can be accelerated.

The iIoO is only default inspection points. For a full list of the in/out chain running on your firewalls run `fw ctl chain` from SPLAT.

Also see this old but still good reference document http://www.checkpoint.com/techsupport/downloads/html/ethereal/fw_monitor_rev1_01.pdf.

Hope this helps.